# Steps to make application live

Tags: android

Though I have created couple of applications in *Android*, I have not much idea of making it live. Can someone mention all the steps which are to be followed for making the application live starting from completion of application.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by live?

Comment: If by `making the app live`, you mean to say, `publish the app`, then see this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Comment: Exactly, I meant publishing my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this..

**Publishing on Android Market**

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html